# Whats's the proper way to loop through an array for an api in laravel 5.1

Tags: arrays, laravel-5.1

I am trying to loop through an array. I have experimented a bit but it's not working properly. it outputs.but it doesn't loop through everything I have in my database. this is my code for my ApiController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        foreach (Post::all() as $post )

        return array(
            'results' => [
                array('id' =>$post->title,
                    'marketname' => $post->subtitle),

            ]
        );
    }
}
```

also the curly bracket just before last is highlighted in my editor. When I hover over it, it says it's expecting a return. But if I move the return to where it says it should be, I get no output. To be clear I want to display something like this

```
"results": [
{
"id": "1002336",
"marketname": "0.2 Harvest Home Echo Park Market"
},
{
"id": "1006207",
"marketname": "0.3 Echo Park Market"
},
{
"id": "1003343",
"marketname": "0.4 La Familia Verde Farmers Market"
},
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the results first, and then return them.

```php
public function index()
{
    $results = array();
    foreach (Post::all() as $post)
    {
        $results[] = array('id' => $post->title, 'marketname' => $post->subtitle);
    }

    return array('results' => $results);
}
```

The reason you're not getting the expected output is because you're returning prematurely after the first iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clean, concise answer.  Here's the code

```
public function index() {
     return Post::get(['title as id', 'subtitle as marketname']);
}
```

Comment: I removed a lot of unnecessary noise from your answer.  While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it.